# How does `inspectcode.exe /properties` work?

Tags: resharper

`inspectcode.exe /help` from [ReSharper's Command Line Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/command-line.html) says:

`/properties : MSBuild properties.`

How does it work? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a way of overriding MSBuild properties that are used when the solution is loaded. This way, you can e.g. override the default setting of "treat warnings as errors" in the solution to force it on in a continuous integration setting.

You use it by passing in a key/value pair separated with an equals sign, e.g. `/properties:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true`. If you want to pass multiple properties through, separate them with a semi-colon, e.g. `/properties:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true;DoSomethingElse=false`.

You can see more details in the [online help](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/Introducing+InspectCode#IntroducingInspectCode-properties).